# How can I change the speed of audio being played? (Using Clip as well as AudioPlayer.player.start()?)

Tags: java, audio-streaming

How can I change the speed of audio being played in a Java program (Using Clip as well as AudioPlayer.player.start()?)

Answer (score 2):

[Increase playback speed of sound file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760128/increase-playback-speed-of-sound-file-in-java)

Comment: I'm the guy that asked that question. If you tell me what doesn't work, I might be able to help fix it.

Comment: I think you should play around with the sample rate:
http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SampleRateConverter.html