# Can we use the Clip library in java to play the song at a different frequency

Tags: java, audio, javasound, clip

I know we can use Clip to play a song using clip.start(). However, is there a function in Clip that allows us to play the song at a different frequency from the original song?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase playback speed of sound file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760128/increase-playback-speed-of-sound-file-in-java).

Comment: Note the same crude technique shown in my answer to the duplicate question is also implemented for the `fastForward` & `fastRewind` modes in ..[`BigClip`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9470886/418556). ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a clip.open(AudioFormat format, byte[] data, int offset, int bufferSize) where you can change AudioFormat freqency. In the folowing link there is code example http://jvalentino2.tripod.com/dft/index.html