# Audio - Byte to Int and back in java

Tags: java, audio, type-conversion, javasound

I'm playing around with looping a sound snippet at succesively faster speeds, for the fun of it, and have stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760128/increase-playback-speed-of-sound-file-in-java/6404263#6404263), which solves it nicely, I guess. It does get kind of buggy when you go to high speeds, because it drops out anything in between and just takes one byte every so often. So I wanted to change it to take the average of all bytes in a stretch within the array. Problem is, bytes don't lend themselves to be divided by ints, and I'm a bit stupid when it comes to changing from bytes to ints. My solution was to do this (again complementing from the mentioned question.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
 import javax.sound.sampled.*;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.io.File;

 class AcceleratePlayback {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int playBackSpeed = 3;
     File soundFile;
         if (args.length>0) {
             try {
                 playBackSpeed = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.exit(1);
             }
         }
         System.out.println("Playback Rate: " + playBackSpeed);

         JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
         chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
         soundFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

         System.out.println("FILE: " + soundFile);
         AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
         AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();

         int frameSize = af.getFrameSize();

         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] b = new byte[2^16];
         int read = 1;
         while( read>-1 ) {
             read = ais.read(b);
             if (read>0) {
                 baos.write(b, 0, read);
             }
         }
         System.out.println("End entire: \t" + new Date());

        //This is the important bit

         byte[] b1 = baos.toByteArray();
         byte[] b2 = new byte[b1.length/playBackSpeed];
         for (int ii=0; ii<b2.length/frameSize; ii++) {
             for (int jj=0; jj<frameSize; jj++) {
                     int b3=0;  
             for (int kk = 0; kk < playBackSpeed; kk++){
              b3 = b3+(int)b1[(ii*frameSize*playBackSpeed)+jj+kk];  
             }
             b3 = b3/playBackSpeed;
             b2[(ii*frameSize)+jj] = (byte)b3;
             }
         }
        //ends here

         System.out.println("End sub-sample: \t" + new Date());

         ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b2);
         AudioInputStream aisAccelerated = new AudioInputStream(bais, af, b2.length);
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         clip.open(aisAccelerated);
         clip.loop(2*playBackSpeed);
         clip.start();

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit?");
     }
}
```

I do realize this is probably the wrong way to do it, but I'm not sure what else I could do, any thoughts??

Best, Alex.

Comment: I don't think your approach will work.  The average of a sinusoidal signal over an integral number of wavelengths is 0.  If not an integral number of wavelengths, the average will decrease for the larger the number of frames analyzed.

Comment: Yes, sure, but that only counts for sinusoidal signals and for speedups that make the integration window fall exactly over a integral number of periods. Anyhow, since the signal is digitally sampled, there is a limit to that too. But my gripe is with the byte-int conversion anyhow.

Comment: Right, so the correct way of saying it is "that only applies to periodic signals when the speedup happens to throw the sampling area into a integer number of periods." My idea was to play around with speeding up loops of non-harmonic sounds (bristling, rustling, clapping) up to make harmonic sounds. It works with analog recordings pretty well, I'm pretty sure it will break down relatively quick, because of the sampling rate and so on, but I thought I might get to 440 hz without major problems if I do it right with proper interpolation and so on.

Comment: But I stress again, it is definitely **not** the average that you want.  ..I wish Phil would happen by this thread, perhaps he could explain better. :(

Comment: Ok, my thought was that just dropping out everything in between would be worse, but given a high enough sampling rate, maybe it's ok. Anyhow, if you want him to find this thread, maybe upvote? ;)

Comment: *"maybe upvote?"*  A question would have to contain an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & have an accepted answer before I'd up-vote.  Just the way I am.  I did something better though.  Added the Java Sound tag.  I'm almost certain he is one of the few people who follow it.

Comment: Ok, sscce included I guess. Works for me at least! The answer I'm not so sure.

Comment: *"Ok, sscce included I guess"*  OK - I'm breaking my own rule.  That is a nice SSCCE & the question deserves an up-vote.  We'll just hope for the answer (& acceptance).  :)

Comment: Neat to see my name mentioned, but I think I'm getting more cred than deserved! The linear interpolation should work without doing any sort of computations with the skipped bytes. You might also want to do some smoothing between the two ends of your audio data to prevent a discontinuity at the looping point. Am not enough of an engineer to explain why we can ignore the skipped bytes. Some use fancier interpolation, though, e.g., quadratics or higher for slightly better fidelity. But my audio engineer friend told me linear interpolation was all I needed for what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since my earlier "solution" was cited, I'll lay out what I use for variable speed playback in a more detail. I confess, I don't totally understand the approach used in this question, and so am not going to make an attempt to improve upon the code. I'm risking "not answering the question" in doing this, but perhaps the increased detail about using linear interpolation will show that this can be a sufficient way to make the higher-speed loops you are going for.

I'm NOT claiming the approach that I came up with is the best. I'm not a sound engineer. But it seems to work. (Am always grateful for any suggested improvements.)

This is for a sound library I've made for my own games. It is based on the idea of a Java Clip, but with some extra capabilities. In my library, there's a place to store data, and another couple structures for playback, one for concurrent single plays, and another for looping. Both allow vari-speed, even to the extent of playing the sound backwards.

To load and hold the "clip" data, I just use a single int[], called 'clipData', but I use it for both L & R, so odd & even ints are for either ear.

Loading 'clipData' initially:

```
    while((bytesRead = ais.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1)
    {
        bufferIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 0, n = bytesRead / 2; i < n; i ++)
        {
            clipData[(int)clipIdx++] = 
                    ( buffer[(int)bufferIdx++] & 0xff )
                    | ( buffer[(int)bufferIdx++] << 8 ) ;
        }
    }
```

For playback, the object that holds this data array has two get() methods. The first is for normal speed. An int is used to index into the clipData array (maybe should be a 'long', for larger audio files!):

```
public double[] get(int idx) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    idx *= 2; // assumed: stereo data

    double[] audioVals = new double[2];
    audioVals[0] = clipData[idx++];
    audioVals[1] = clipData[idx];

    return audioVals;
}
```

Maybe returning a float array is acceptable, in place of the double[]?

Here is the enhanced get() method for variable speed. It uses linear interpolation to account for the fractional part of the double used as an index into the clipData:

```
public double[] get(double idx) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    int intPart = (int)idx * 2;
    double fractionalPart = idx * 2 - intPart;

    int valR1 = clipData[intPart++];
    int valL1 = clipData[intPart++]; 
    int valR2 = clipData[intPart++];
    int valL2 = clipData[intPart];

    double[] audioVals = new double[2];

    audioVals[0] = (valR1 * (1 - fractionalPart) 
            + valR2 * fractionalPart);

    audioVals[1] = (valL1 * (1 - fractionalPart) 
            + valL2 * fractionalPart);      

    return audioVals;
}
```

The while(playing) loop (for loading data into the playback SourceDataLine) has a variable associated with the clipData which I call "cursor" that iterates through the sound data array. For normal playback, 'cursor' is incremented by 1, and tested to make sure it goes back to zero when it reaches the end of the clipData.

You could write something like: `audioData = clipData.get(cursor++)` to read successive frames of the data.

For varispeed, the above would be more like this:

```
audioData = clipData.get(cursor += speedIncrement);
```

'speedIncrement' is a double. If it is set to 2.0, the playback is twice as fast. If it is set to 0.5, it is half as fast. If you put in the right checks you can even make speedIncrement equal a negative value for reverse playback.

This works as long as the speed doesn't go above the Nyquist value (at least theoretically). And again, you have to test to make sure 'cursor' hasn't gone off the edge of the clipData, but restarts at the appropriate spot at the other end of the sound data array.

Hope this helps!

Another note: you may want to rewrite the above get() methods to send a buffer's worth of reads instead of single frames. I'm currently experimenting with doing things on a per-frame basis. I think it makes the code a little easier to understand, and helps with per-frame processing and responsiveness, but it surely slows things down.

Comment: Hi Phil, nice of you to give a complete answer like this. I've in the meantime read up on undersampling and the Nyquist theorem, and I believe I was having an aliasing problem. When you simply subsample that way you get spurious low-frequency components which will mess up your data, the same thing goes for images actually. I guess what I need to do is to do a low-pass filter before undersampling, that should solve my problems. I guess fractional sampling with linear interpolation will do ok for moderate speedups, but I was aiming to the 100's to 1000's of times, so... we'll see. Thanks a ton!